# Python OSError when running sys.meta_path[2].find_distributions() (required for pytest)

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following code:

```
list(sys.meta_path[2].find_distributions())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\windows\\system32\\ C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib'
```

Something similar to the code above is run as part of `pytest` startup which fails with the same error. (`config/init.py:1055`) However, for some reason it tries to access the concatenation of the my working directory and the python lib directory as a single folder. My `pythonpath` and `path` environment variables look fine and definitely don't contain anything like this. The problem persists both inside and outside a virtualenv.

This is my `pythonpath`:

```
'C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages; C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib; C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs;C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev'
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong with my python setup to cause a error like this, or know of a way to run pytest while skipping the module discovery step?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces after `;` from your PYTHONPATH:

```
'C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages;C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib;C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs;C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev'
```